# Could not load type "locality"

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I hope to use a form inside my controller,but I get everytime the following error :

```
Could not load type "locality"
```

and here is ly form class :

```
class LocationType extends AbstractType 
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();

    $builder->add('province','entity',array(
                   'class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Province',
                   'property' => 'name'));

    $refreshLocality = function ($form, $province) use ($factory) {
        $form->add($factory->createNamed('entity','locality',null, array(
            'class'         => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Locality',
            'property'      => 'name',
            'label'         => 'Locality',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($province) {
                                   $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('locality')
                                                    ->innerJoin('locality.province', 'province');

                                   if($province instanceof Province) {
                                       $qb = $qb->where('locality.province = :province')
                                                ->setParameter('province', $province);
                                   } elseif(is_numeric($province)) {
                                       $qb = $qb->where('province.id = :province_id')
                                                ->setParameter('province_id', $province);
                                   } else {
                                       $qb = $qb->where('province.id = 1');
                                   }

                                   return $qb;
                               }
             )));
    };

    $builder->add('address','text',array(
                    'required' => false));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($refreshLocality) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if($data == null)
           $refreshLocality($form, null); //As of beta2, when a form is created setData(null) is called first

        if($data instanceof Location) {
            $refreshLocality($form, $data->getLocality()->getProvince());
            }
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function (FormEvent $event) use ($refreshLocality) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if(array_key_exists('province', $data)) {
            $refreshLocality($form, $data['province']);
        }
    });
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Location'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'acme_demobundle_locationtype';
}

}
```

Then I called this class in my controller :

```
    public function indexAction()
{
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new \Acme\DemoBundle\Form\LocationType());

    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

        }
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());;
}
```

and here my twig :

```
    <form action="{{ path('_demo') }}" method="POST" id="contact_form">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}


    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="symfony-button-grey" />
</form>
```

when I had the error above I tried to register your form in the section services in service.xml :

```
 <service id="form.type.acme_demobundle_locationtype" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Form\LocationType">
    <tag name="form.type" alias="acme_demobundle_locationtype" />
    </service>
```

but I get the same error,any idea?

Comment: I haven't used `FormFactory` before but don't you maybe need to swap  arguments `'entity'`,`'locality'` in `createNamed` call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the arguments that you passed to `createNamed()`:

```
$form->add($factory->createNamed('entity','locality',null, array(
```

should be

```
$form->add($factory->createNamed('locality', 'entity', null, array(
```

In fact, you can even simplify your code to

```
$form->add('locality', 'entity', array(
```